# Retrieving jobs of an expired access device

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I had private access to a quantum computer, but the access is expired. So Can I access to my jobs done on it ?
The '''backend.retrieve_job('')''' ​can't work because I cant load the backend (no access).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the job id, you can do `provider.backend.retrieve_job(job_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you log into your IBMQ account and then go to your Quantum Lab, on the left hand menu you will see an icon that looks like a "play" symbol with a counterclockwise circle around it.  If you click this, you will have access to the results of your past jobs.

I have never used a paid device, so I am not sure if those results will also be found here, but I can find anything I have ran in this list.